# java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, android-json

```
@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

    String path = null;
    String response = null;
    HashMap<String, String> request = null;
    JSONObject requestJson = null;
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = null;
    HttpPost httpPost = null;
    StringEntity requestString = null;
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = null;

    // get the username and password
    Log.i("Email", params[0]);
    Log.i("Password", params[1]);

    try {

        path = "http://192.xxx.x.xxx/xxxxService/UsersService.svc/UserAuthentication";
        new URL(path);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        // set the API request
        request = new HashMap<String, String>();
        request.put(new String("Email"), params[0]);
        request.put(new String("Password"), params[1]);
        request.entrySet().iterator();

        // Store locations in JSON
        requestJson = new JSONObject(request);
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpPost = new HttpPost(path);
        requestString = new StringEntity(requestJson.toString());

        // sets the post request as the resulting string
        httpPost.setEntity(requestString);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        // Handles the response
        responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);

        responseJson = new JSONObject(response);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    try {
        responseJson = new JSONObject(response);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }


    return responseJson;
}
```

I'm using this code to login to my app.

```
responseJson = new JSONObject(response);
```

I'm getting "success" for the response, but responseJson value is "null"

This is what I got:

```
Error converting result org.json.JSONException: Value Fail of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I t will be good if i can get a salution
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your response? Have you tried to put response in http://json.parser.online.fr/beta/

Comment: Please show the response from `httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler)`

Comment: i think ur service is local hence cannot get response from broswer from above url

Comment: Here also i'm getting Success for the response.
response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);

Comment: I think your response is not json or invalid json format.

Comment: It was an issue with the response, I go it fixed now.. thanx guys..

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
Object json = new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
if (json instanceof JSONArray) {
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) json;
 // your logic
}else if(json instanceof JSONObject){
//your logic
}
```